# Pass variable between subs

Tags: excel, vba

I have a userform that populates 11 textboxes based off two criteria. I would like the row that was used to populate the fields to be stored and used for the next sub, where the information is changed and updated to the same row it was taken from. I'm not sure how to have the `currentrow` variable passed to the next sub, but that's the big issue I'm having, as I constantly get some sort of error based off `currentrow` not being defined.

If you could please provide code as to exactly how to fix this, or for extra appreciation, on how to change the first part of the code to be able to search for only part of the value instead of the whole value, I would be so grateful.

```
Option Explicit
Private currentrow As Long

Sub MainMacro()
currentrow = cel.Row
CommandButton2 (currentrow)
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim ws As Worksheet, cel As Range
    Set ws = Sheets("The Goods")
    For Each cel In ws.Cells(2, 2).Resize(ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row).Cells
        If cel.Value = Me.txtname.Value And cel.Offset(, 2).Value = Me.txtsearch.Value Then
            currentrow = cel.Row
            Me.txt1.Value = cel.Offset(, 3).Value
            Me.txt2.Value = cel.Offset(, 1).Value
            Me.txt3.Value = cel.Offset(, 4).Value
            Me.txt4.Value = cel.Offset(, 5).Value
            Me.txt5.Value = cel.Offset(, 6).Value
            Me.txt6.Value = cel.Offset(, 7).Value
            Me.txt7.Value = cel.Offset(, 8).Value
            Me.txt8.Value = cel.Offset(, 9).Value
            Me.txt9.Value = cel.Offset(, 10).Value
            Me.txt10.Value = cel.Offset(, 11).Value
            Me.txt11.Value = cel.Offset(, 12).Value
        End If
    Next cel

End Sub

Function find_irow()
    currentrow = cel.Row
    Call CommandButton2
End Function

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Dim aa As String, bb As String, cc As String, dd As String, ee As String, ff As String, gg As String, hh As String, ii As String, jj As String, kk As String


    aa = txt1.Value
    bb = txt2.Value
    cc = txt3.Value
    dd = txt4.Value
    ee = txt5.Value
    ff = txt6.Value
    gg = txt7.Value
    hh = txt8.Value
    ii = txt9.Value
    jj = txt10.Value
    kk = txt11.Value

With Sheets("The Goods")
        Cells(currentrow, 5).Value = aa
        Cells(currentrow, 3).Value = bb
        Cells(currentrow, 6).Value = cc
        Cells(currentrow, 7).Value = dd
        Cells(currentrow, 8).Value = ee
        Cells(currentrow, 9).Value = ff
        Cells(currentrow, 10).Value = gg
        Cells(currentrow, 11).Value = hh
        Cells(currentrow, 12).Value = ii
        Cells(currentrow, 13).Value = jj
        Cells(currentrow, 14).Value = kk
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: The easy answer is to define the variable once, at the file level.  In other words, right after `Option Explicit`, write `Private currentrow As Long`.  Remove the other places you define it with `Dim`.

Comment: I know I already left you this link earlier, but it really is worth a read: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/understanding-scope-and-visibility

Comment: @BrianMStafford Unfortunately I'm still getting a run-time error '1004'': application-defined or object defined error for some reason at `cells(currentrow, 5).Value = aa`.

Comment: @Tara - `Debug.Print currentrow` or add a watch. What is its value? Probably 0.

Comment: It shows currentrow = 0

Comment: There's no row `0`, hence the error.

Comment: The code you've posted can't raise error 1004 at run-time, because it would fail to compile. `cel` is not defined in `MainMacro` (or in `find_irow` - and that function isn't returning anything), and as far as I can tell `CommandButton2` is an ActiveX button object, not a procedure. Read up on scoping as @BigBen suggested, and then the language feature that's best suited for passing objects & values between procedures, is parameters.

Comment: Thank you, I edited my code shown above, which now stores the currentrow during commandbutton2_click(), but does not change the values on the sheet as I would like but does not give an error. Do you happen to know how to fix this? @BigBen

Answer (score -3):

Once your sub `MainMacro` is done running, your system will clear the memory for the variable `currentRow`. That being said, the variables value is gone and you can't use it within another sub anymore. A possible solution is to store the value of the variable `currentRow` in a cell and call it within the second sub again like so:

```
Sub MainMacro()
Dim currentrow As Integer
currentrow = cel.Row
CommandButton2 (currentrow)
Cells(100,100).value = currentrow
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

currentrow = cells(100,100).value

[...]

End Sub

etc.
```

There might be different solutions as well, but this works just fine. I personally often use such "data containers" across my projects. Just make the font color white or such so you won't actually see the data contained in your container cell.

PS: Try to use camel**C**ase in your codes. This will make it easier for you to read through the code.

Comment: I thought about adding a comment, so I will. This is not a great idea. An appropriate answer to this question would have discussed variable scope. Writing the value to a random worksheet cell isn't code - it's a hack that should never be employed. This works just fine... until the user clears that cell, or the row gets deleted, or you overwrite data you need. So it doesn't actually work as a true answer to this question would.

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up. True that, will consider this for my own projects in future.